# Line bottom of Material UI icon with bottom of text

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have this code:

```
<td>
    <WarningAmberIcon sx={{ color: '#cc0000' }} />&nbsp;&nbsp; If you cannot print in colour, please <a href="https://www.aviva.ie/insurance/car-insurance/faqs/#documents" target="_blank"> click here for further instruction</a>
</td>
```

When displayed on screen it looks like this:

[image]

How can the bottom of the icon be lined up with the bottom of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom style with css positioning

ex: `sx={{ position: 'relative', top: '5px' }}`

or you can wrap those icon and text in a new container and make it a flex container. then change the `align-items` value to `flex-end`

Answer (score 1):

Using flex is one way of doing this:

```
<td>
 <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center">
  your content
 </div>
</td>
```

You might notice that text is not perfectly center, setting `line-height` to `1` will solve it.